# Is there any way i can see the effective build configuration of a sub project in gradle (in intelij)?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I have a root project and few sub projects.
The root project, in it's `build.gradle` file, adds some configurations, tasks, plugins and dependencies to `subprojects`.

In the subprojects's `build.gradle` file i have added additional deps, plugins, task and conf.
**Now i want to know the effective build configuration of the subproject.**  Is it possible to get this info using any `gradle` command. If yes, is the same possible in `intellij idea`

(In maven I can get the effective configuration of any project using `mvn help:effective-pom` no matter if it's a submodule or has a parent pom. And in intellij idea i can right-click on the pom and choose to view the effective pom. It's quite simple. )

**Edit:**
Like Rob mentioned in comments - The below commands can be used to find any projects (parent or child/sub-project) dependencies in various scopes/configuration.
`/gradlew :<sub-project-name>:dependencies`
and
`./gradlew :<sub-project-name<:dependencies --configuration <name-of-configuration>`

And the Maven equivallent of the above would be `mvn dependency:tree`.

But I am interested in knowing other info also besides dependencies. **Other info like:** tasks, plugins, repositories etc that is applicable for the sub-project (i.e defined in the sub-project + inherited or applied from/by parent project.

maven `mvn help:effective-pom` == gradle `????`

Comment: Are you trying to get a resolved dependency tree? If you want to list the dependency tree of a subproject, you can run `./gradlew :<sub-project-name>:dependencies` which will list each dependency on each configuration.

If you want to list the dependencies on a given configuration, run `./gradlew :<sub-project-name<:dependencies --configuration <name-of-configuration>`

Comment: @RobSchwartz - appreciate ur suggestion. What you suggested is equivalent to     `mvn dependency:tree`.  But what I am trying to find is gradle equivalent to `mvn help:effective-pom`. Plz see my edit.